# How to use API in autoCompletetextview?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, autocompletetextview

I want to make an `AutoCompleteTextview` with RapidApi [Urban Dictionary](https://rapidapi.com/community/api/urban-dictionary) where I would filter words by input. But I am a beginner. I've searched a lot tutorials on it. But I did not find any such that. I just get this from RapidApi

```
val client = OkHttpClient()

val request = Request.Builder()
    .url("https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define?term=wat")
    .get()
    .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "8345a8b4d6ms...")
    .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com")
    .build()

val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
```

and in `AutoCompleteTextview` [tutorial](https://youtu.be/JB3ETK5mh3c) I see that we need an array but with above code I don't know how can I get an array from the response. I want a full answer on it.

Comment: Can you add to this question a formatted version of what is in the `response` object after this call? Please also describe in the question what is wrong with it.

Comment: I want to know how can i get the list of words from the response.

Answer (score 1):

You need

- a library like [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for sending requests to any API.
- another library like [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) as JSON parser to convert responses into data objects.
- Using these response data objects, populate arrayAdapter to use it with `AutoCompleteTextView`

Comment: Umm.. well i already know these things, i want a complete solution, please take some time and give me a complete solution.

Comment: Then please start implementing it yourself! If you get stuck somewhere, you will get help here for sure.

Comment: @mr.groot: I would say Varsha is completely correct. Stack Overflow is intended to render help, i.e. a shared amount of assistance. There is broadly still an expectation that the question author is willing to help themselves.

Comment: Yes @halfer you are right, after versha's suggestion I realised and started doing it by myself. if i stuck anywhere I'll ask in the comment until i get a major problem.